# A healthy disrespect for authority

Tags: phrase-usage

To to mind, the collocation "a healthy disrespect for authority" means that we ought to respect experts normally, but in some rare cases they might also make mistakes. So it implies that we should learn things with criticism. I am not quite sure whether it is correct.

What is the meaning and implication of the phrase, and are there negative usages of it?

Comment: You're completely mistaken in thinking *a healthy disrespect for authority* implies anything along the lines of *respect experts "normally"*. It's a loaded term implying authorities (or their opinions) should ***never*** be respected simply because they're in positions of power (or are recognised by others as having special knowledge of a subject). Essentially it's a (somewhat cliched) endorsement of scepticism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a twist on the phrase "a healthy **respect** for authority", which emerges in the 1890s as a description of the proper attitude of children toward elders, students towards teachers, of the masses toward the classes, and of citizens towards government.

From the 1950s it was used so often it became a cliché, and promptly spawned its antithesis "a healthy **dis**respect for authority", expressing the belligerent mistrust most people actually feel toward the domestic, academic, social and political "betters" who bully and exploit them.

Both phrases are now so stale I would avoid using them.

Comment: Don't forget the old saw "Bullying begins at home". (OK, so I just made that up, but it's true, innit?) Parents, aunts & uncles, elder siblings & cousins, & even the hired help (babysitters, in my case) are the first symbols of authority that almost everyone encounters. This most certainly leads to an _unhealthy disrespect for authority_. This & the very negative attitude most people have about the police. My younger son's mother & I never badmouthed the Taiwanese police & never had a run-in with them, but our son learned to dislike & fear them from somewhere. Probably a common social meme.

Comment: @BillFranke Quite so, and I have edited to incorporate that obervation; though it quite spoils my triads to foursquare them.

Comment: Traids are for lawyers, [four-squares for Freemasons](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on_the_square), & balanced sentences for good writers. You know what category you're.

Comment: @BillFranke What I say three times is true. Four may be suspected of exaggeration.

Comment: Now you're thinking like a lawyer! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The word *healthy* is a very interesting adjective, in that it has two almost contradictory meanings.

The word *healthy* can be used to refer to *a large sum of*; for example:

> They sold their house for a healthy profit.

That sentence tells me that they didn't just make a little bit of money on their house, they made a **lot**. Had they originally bought the house for $100,000, and sold it for $120,000 I wouldn't use the word *healthy* to describe that 20% profit. Perhaps if they sold it for something more like $170,000 – although there's no fixed point where the adjective can suddenly be applied. More importantly, though, there's no upper limit to how much you could have until the word *healthy* would no longer be fitting. $260,000? That's a healthy profit, too.

The other way *healthy* can be used, though, is to mean *just enough of something to be more positive than negative*.  It can be found in phrases such as:

- A healthy amount of attention
- A healthy amount of self-esteem
- A healthy amount of mistrust

Under such usages, the word *healthy* acknowledges that it's indeed quite possible to have too much of something, as well as too little of something, but we should strive for that "just right" amount.

For example, in the case of skepticism, it's indeed possible to be too skeptical (to the point where you become a grouchy cynic), or to have too little skepticism (where you become gullible and vulnerable to swindlers). If self-esteem is too high, you can become egocentric, and if it's too low, you can become depressed.

So "a healthy disrespect for authority" means as you say: too much disrespect leads to chaos, but too little disrespect leads to mass conformity, which can stifle creativity and innovation.

Are there negative uses for it? All language is context dependent, and thus can be used at inappropriate times. If I had been arrested, for example, and was on my way to the police station, that probably wouldn't be a good time to [wax eloquent](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/wax+eloquent) about my healthy disrespect for authority.